# php compile less file using lessc via nodejs on windows 7

Tags: php, windows, node.js, exec, less

I am trying to compile less file using php, and I am trying to use lessc which I installed as nodejs module on my windows 7

I am trying to do :

```
$command = lessc %s -compress %s
```

via

```
exec($command, $output);
```

and if I do this via **cmd** it works fine but I can't execute it using above command in php :(.

the path which works are relative to my drive (E:/wamp/my-project/less/hello.less)

Any body knows what I am doing wrong?

Note: I know how I can use **lessphp** compiler, and I am already using it but I would like to use **lessc** module installed via **nodejs**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get the output of the command when it fails?  It's possible that `lessc` isn't directly available in your path.  If you installed it via `npm install -g` then it will likely be in %appdata%, which is a user path'd directory.  It really depends upon how the php process gets initiated, but my guess is that this path won't work.

If I need to use an npm module like this, I usually `npm install` it locally, and invoke the path to lessc.cmd from a relative path to my program.

Hope this helps.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Justin, I haven't digged it again yet, will give it another go in coming weeks, as I am starting to have issues with lessphp (its not a clone of less.js, so :(). Will let you know if it works or not.